# 2 WAY BINDING RAZOR PAGES

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, binding, razor-pages

How can i make 2 way binding in razor pages?

I nedd to call in:

- cshtml Input with value="@test">
- cshtml.cs use the value of @test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample to bind data in cshtml and cshtml.cs:

cshtml.cs(You can use `test` value in cshtml.cs with `test` directly):

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string test { get; set; }
    }
```

cshtml:

```
<input asp-for="test"/>
```

or

```
<input name="test" value="@Model.test" />
```

Comment: Result! Thanks for help :P